# Move / Copy File Operations in Java

Tags: java, file, copy, move

Is there a standard Java library that handles common file operations such as moving/copying files/folders?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Here's how to do this with `java.nio` operations:

```
public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if(!destFile.exists()) {
        destFile.createNewFile();
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();

        // previous code: destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        // to avoid infinite loops, should be:
        long count = 0;
        long size = source.size();              
        while((count += destination.transferFrom(source, count, size-count))<size);
    }
    finally {
        if(source != null) {
            source.close();
        }
        if(destination != null) {
            destination.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if the file exists will the content be append or overwritten?

Comment: @Rigo This moves only files, i'm not able to move directories

Comment: It's worth noting that Java 7 has simpler [copy/move methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html).

Comment: Any reason why `File.renameTo` isn't as good as `Files.move`?

Comment: @Erik Allik: If the operation fails, `Files.move` will tell you *why* instead of simply returning `false`. And `Files.move` can handle moves that are not simple renames, i.e. need a copy-and-delete.

Comment: `Files.move()` requires API level 26 on Android, `File.renameTo()` doesn't.

Answer (score 41):

Not yet, but the [New NIO (JSR 203)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=203) will have support for these common operations.

In the meantime, there are a few things to keep in mind.

[File.renameTo](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)) generally works only on the same file system volume. I think of this as the equivalent to a "mv" command. Use it if you can, but for general copy and move support, you'll need to have a fallback.

When a rename doesn't work you will need to actually copy the file (deleting the original with [File.delete](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete()) if it's a "move" operation). To do this with the greatest efficiency, use the [FileChannel.transferTo](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferTo(long,%20long,%20java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel)) or [FileChannel.transferFrom](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom(java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20long,%20long)) methods. The implementation is platform specific, but in general, when copying from one file to another, implementations avoid transporting data back and forth between kernel and user space, yielding a big boost in efficiency.

Answer (score 17):

Check out:
http://commons.apache.org/io/

It has copy, and as stated the JDK already has move.

Don't implement your own copy method.  There are so many floating out there...

Comment: Commons IO has limitations with respect to the size of files it can copy. For a general-purpose solution, a more robust implementation would be expected.

Comment: Implementing one's own copy method is trivial and means you won't be dependent on an entire library. *Do* implement your own

Comment: Copy method is far from trivial.  You can easily make a correct one that doesn't perform using Streams, and fast but incorrect one using NIO.  Never implement your own utilities when there are quality libraries out there.

Comment: A copy method *is* non-trivial, and Apache Commons can't handle a common use case: information too large for main memory. A library intended for managing mass storage should have bounds on its memory-consumption, which Apache Commons move method lacks.

Comment: @Pyrolistical `Never implement your own utilities when there are quality libraries out there.` Uhh suure, if you never have to worry about licensing.

Answer (score 10):

Previous answers seem to be outdated.

Java's [File.renameTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) is probably the easiest solution for API 7, and seems to work fine.
Be carefull IT DOES NOT THROW EXCEPTIONS, but returns true/false!!!

Note that there seem to be problems with it  in previous versions (same as [NIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29)).

If you need to use a previous version, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000183/reliable-file-renameto-alternative-on-windows).

Here's an example for API7:

```
File f1= new File("C:\\Users\\.....\\foo");
File f2= new File("C:\\Users\\......\\foo.old");
System.err.println("Result of move:"+f1.renameTo(f2));
```

Alternatively:

```
System.err.println("Move:" +f1.toURI() +"--->>>>"+f2.toURI());
Path b1=Files.move(f1.toPath(),  f2.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE ,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING ););
System.err.println("Move: RETURNS:"+b1);
```

Comment: If you are getting "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." exception on the second piece of code, remember to close the file before moving it.....

Comment: There are other unexpected situations in which it fails, e.g. on linux if you have two different filesystems mounted under /mnt/a /mnt/b, you cannot rename a file /mnt/a/file1 to /mnt/b/file2, since it actually is a move operation, File.renameTo would fail in this case.

Comment: This is the best solution. Just use Files.move() if you are concerned about the rename operation failing.

Answer (score 8):

Google's Guava library also has these:

http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html

Answer (score 7):

Try to use [org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) (General file manipulation utilities). Facilities are provided in the following methods:

> (1) [FileUtils.moveDirectory(File srcDir, File destDir)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29) => Moves a
>   directory.
>
> (2) [FileUtils.moveDirectoryToDirectory(File src, File destDir, boolean
>   createDestDir)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveDirectoryToDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File,%20boolean%29) => Moves a directory to another directory.
>
> (3) [FileUtils.moveFile(File srcFile, File destFile)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29) => Moves a file.
>
> (4) [FileUtils.moveFileToDirectory(File srcFile, File destDir, boolean
>   createDestDir)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFileToDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File,%20boolean%29) => Moves a file to a directory.
>
> (5) [FileUtils.moveToDirectory(File src, File destDir, boolean
>   createDestDir)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveToDirectory%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File,%20boolean%29) => Moves a file or directory to the destination
>   directory.

It's simple, easy and fast.

Comment: Are these functions atomic?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting observation:
Tried to copy the same file via various java classes and printed time in nano seconds.

Duration using FileOutputStream byte stream: 4 965 078

Duration using BufferedOutputStream: 1 237 206

Duration using (character text Reader: 2 858 875

Duration using BufferedReader(Buffered character text stream: 1 998 005

Duration using (Files NIO copy): 18 351 115

when using Files Nio copy option it took almost 18 times longer!!!
Nio is the slowest option to copy files and BufferedOutputStream looks like the fastest. I used the same simple text file for each class.