# Java File.renameTo fails

Tags: java

In Java  File.renameTo fails.

```
File file = new File("a.txt");
File loadedFile = new File("a.txt.loaded");

if (file.renameTo(loadedFile)) {
     // task 
} else {
    // Throw Exception 
}
```

Any idea why it fails. please provide any alternate solution to rename the file.

Comment: is there any exception thrown or error message?

Comment: What operating system?  Is the file in use?  Can you rename it on the command line?  Does the destination file exist?  Is something locking it?  What does `lsof` say?  Or process explorer?  In other words, *what have you tried*?

Comment: my car's not working...what's wrong with it?  Do you really expect people to be able to help you with the level of detail you have provided?

Comment: @hvgotcodes: uh oh, better post to http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Mind Reader or Crystal Ball](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/172496)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reliable File.renameTo() alternative on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000183/reliable-file-renameto-alternative-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

It can fail if

- The file to which you want to rename to already exist (I think Windows only) In this case, just delete the target file first and then rename to it.
- The file to which you want to rename to is locked
- The file you want to rename is currently opened (Windows only too I think)
- Other stuffs...