# Java file character encoding move/rename in Linux

Tags: java, file-io, encoding, utf-8

I have this java code that renames a file (or directory). There is a problem on Linux when I use some special characters, it works on Windows with these special characters. The way I try it is like this: 
In windows

- I create a direcotory called "326½_6"
- I build a jar-file, and call it (java -jar) directly in the windows cmd (or linux shell), first param is the directory above, second param is a path to a new directory. 
  This works

I then transfer the directory to a Linux server using SFTP (WinSCP). I repeat the steps above, but it doesn't work. I get this output:

Moving /home/user/testarea/326ï¿½_6/ to /home/user/testarea/test5/

--- could not perform rename -------

Is there anyway to make this work on a Linux machine???

the code:

```
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    String source = args[0];
    String dest = args[1];
    System.out.println(" - Moving " + source + " to " + dest);

    File sourceFile = new File(source);
    File destinationFile = new File(dest);

    if (!sourceFile.renameTo(destinationFile)) {
        System.out.println("--- could not perform rename -------");
    }

    System.out.println("Finished moving");
 }
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Java on Linux is expecting file and directory names to be encoded in UTF-8, but when WinSCP creates the directory it encodes the name in latin1 or something similar, and the new name is not valid in UTF-8. Apparently this was the default behavior for WinSCP, [the newer versions use UTF-8 by default](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_utf8).

An easy solution to make Java use the same encoding that SFTP used when creating the directory. This is done by changing the locale when running the JVM:

```
LANG=en_US.iso8859_1 java -jar YourProgram.jar
```

The locale en_US.iso8859_1 has to exist for this to work, though. You might be able to install new locales from the package repositories of your distribution. If not, you can read about [how to define a locale with a specific encoding](http://jonisalonen.com/2012/java-and-file-names-with-invalid-characters/) (and about this file name problem in general) in my blog.

Comment: IS it always encoded as "en_US.iso8859_1" when transferring via SFTP?

Comment: I think SFTP does not change the encoding when transferring, so file names are created with the encoding used on Windows, which is probably windows-1252. It's the same as iso-8859-1 except for the bytes 0x80-0x9f.

Comment: Is there a way to handle "all" platforms mac/win/linux etc? Or should one make sure that users using SFTP must use UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: If you use iso-8859-1 for file names it will "work" for every one, but file names will be mangled for a lot of people. Better to make sure everyone uses UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

May be the file source is not exists. check existance before renameTo

Answer (score 0):

renameTo() is not reliable at all, above all in windows, but also in unix-like system.
What I suggest is perform some checks, create some "retry" mechanism and take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000183/reliable-file-renameto-alternative-on-windows).
Can you specify what encoding are you using (by looking at the tag I think UTF-8) and how do you launch your program?

Comment: I build a jar-file, and call it (java -jar) directly in the linux shell.