# Making a newly made file in java unreadable while its being written too

Tags: java, linux, permissions

Hello i am using the File class in java to write a txt file with over 100,000 lines of information. I am on fedora linux. While the file is being written to i don't want it to be allowed to be read until it is fully completed.

I thought setting the setReadable(false) before having the file be written then at the end setting it to true would work but it did not does anyone know how i can do this correctly

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128038/how-can-i-lock-a-file-using-java-if-possible

Answer (score 1):

Write it with a .tmp extension and then move/rename it to the real extension when finished

```
final File file = new File(filename + ".tmp");

// code to save the text to the file

file.renameTo(new File(filename+ ".txt"))
```

The .renameTo is an atomic action on linux.

Comment: renameTo would not be atomic on Windows, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000183/reliable-file-renameto-alternative-on-windows

Comment: @lbalazscs He mentions fedora linux in his question and there it is atomic

Comment: This will not prevent processes from writing to the file. filename+".tmp" is still writable by any process. The Java NIO package has file-locking.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement that with [transactions from Apache](http://commons.apache.org/transaction/). it allows you to write to files in single transaction. Your base file won't even exist before you commit it

But you can also do that alone. Write your file elsewhere and move it when completed