# Java: rename file in file system (trim the extension)

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to trim the file extension in file system using this way:

```
private void passingFileRename(File f) throws Exception 
{
  String filename = f.getName();
  String ext = ".txt";

  File newfile = new File(filename.substring(0, filename.length() - ext.length()));
  f.renameTo(newfile); 
}
```

But it doesn't work, I get the `filename` but `renameTo` method seems to be locked or something..
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "locked"? It never returns, or are you getting an exception?

Comment: It doing nothing, everything seems to be ok, no exception.. but file is not renamed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000183/reliable-file-renameto-alternative-on-windows). It seems like Java's `file.renameTo(file)` is quite problematic.

Comment: Thanks, this `Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();` really helped :-))