# How do change file names during the execution of the program

Tags: java, file

I have to run some simulations, the output should be in files, the number of outputs can be changed from simulation to the other, for example, the first simulation I use 10 files, the second will be 14 files. let's say I have N files

I declare the `N` files using the following instruction:

```
String path1="C:/Users/Desktop/path1.txt";
File file1 =new File(path1);
```

to write into the file 1 I use this function:

```
write(my outputs list,path1,file1);
```

during the execution, according to some parameters, I select the file to write on it, I would like to do this option without the use of the `switch case` instruction because it is not easy to manage it if the number of files is big.

with switch case it would be something like:

```
int choice1 = number;
switch (choice1) {
case 1 :        
write(outputs ,path1,file1);
break;
case 2 :        
    write(outputs ,path2,file2);
break;
case 3 :
.......
}
```

I would like to replace the switch case with other instruction,

for example, to change the path, I used:

```
String path= "path"+number;
```

where number is the number of the path file to write on it.
then I can call for my function `write(outputs, path, file)`, but
I would like to do the same thing for file, but I do not know how.
Please, any help.

Comment: Why can't you do the same thing for file as you do for path?

Comment: What's wrong with passing your `path` you just made to `write`?

Comment: because  **path** is a 'string'  variable, so it is easy to change it by concatenation with any number.

Comment: I think it could help if you step back for a second and (probably for your self)   write down **exactly** how your naming rules/conventions for files/paths should be. Then try to "translate" that to java; if stuck - ask here. Right now, your question isn't really clear what exactly you want to do; or more precisely, if the way you want to do it is really a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'file.renameTo(someOtherFile)`. This might be important though: [Reliable File.renameTo() alternative on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000183/reliable-file-renameto-alternative-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

The path includes filename so include filename in your path `String` another example, if you want to write files in your app structure:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("folder" + number + "/filename" + number + ".xml").getFile());
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you wanted was set a filename, like appending a number, maybe you can do something like this:

```
String name = file.getName();
int pos = name.lastIndexOf(".");
int number = 1;
name = name.substring(0, pos) + number + name.substring(pos, name.length());
```