# How to Rename files and folder in java file manager application?

Tags: java, file-manager

I am creating a file manager in java.I have a problem when I am trying to rename the files and folders.I am taking the new filename from user input then I am trying to rename the file.

```
popupMenu.rename.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                list.getSelectedValue().toString();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rename");
                final JTextField textField=new JTextField();
                 String s = null;
                 File file2 = new File("newname");
                textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                       s = textField.getText();
                       }
                    });
                Object o = list.getModel().getElementAt(list.getSelectedIndex());
                File file = new File(o.toString());
                //FileUtils.moveFile(file, newFile);
                  file.renameTo(file2);
                  //Files.move(file.toPath(),file.toPath().resolveSibling(textField.getText()));

                frame.add(textField);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
                frame.setSize(200,60);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
```

Please suggest anything mistakes I made.

Also, is there a way I could rename the file similiar to windows by clicking on text.I am displaying the files and folders name by setText(fileName);.Here is my project screenshot

[image]

Comment: What is the problem ? you can change the name ? is there something in your log ?

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000183/reliable-file-renameto-alternative-on-windows ?

Comment: Yes i have tried it but does not found working for me

Comment: reos sir the name is not changing

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
file.renameTo(file2);
```

You aren't looking at the return value, so if it fails, your code just acts like it succeeded.

java.io.File is obsolete.  It is a holdover from Java 1.0, which had a handful of less than ideal design decisions.  Among these was the decision to have many methods of the File class return a value, like C libraries do, instead of throwing an exception on failure.

Change that line of code to this:

```
Files.move(file.toPath(), file2.toPath());
```

The compiler will tell you that you have to catch IOException.  That's a *good thing.*  Do not write an empty `catch` block—that exception will tell you exactly why your attempt to rename the file is failing.  At the very least, a catch block should call `printStackTrace()` on the caught exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
            String oldPath= finalPDFPath;  // old path

            File oldFile= new File(oldPath);

            String newPath= newPDFPath;  // new path
            
            File changeToNewPath = new File(newPath);
            
            if(!oldFile.exists()) {
                System.out.println("no folder");
            }else {
                
                passportFolder.renameTo(changeToNewPath ); // rename old to new path
                
                System.out.println("name changed");
                
            }
```

This code working fine for me.