# JavaZOOM move file after being played

Tags: java, audio, javasound, javax

I'm trying to move a file after its being played.
I'm using javazoom's basicplayer to play my files and I tried

```
player.close();
controler.close();
and DSP.close();
```

and none work

Here is the code I use to play the file

```
public void play(File sound) {
    if (sound.exists()) {

        new Thread("Sound player") {

            public void run() {

                currentSelectedSound = sound;

                try {
                    control.open(currentSelectedSound);
                    control.play();

                    setVolume(currentAudioVolume);
                    setPan(currentAudioPan);
                } catch (BasicPlayerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.err.println("Error!");
                }

            }
        }.start();

    } else {
        Logger.logError(TAG, "File doesn't exist!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so happy it finally works, heres the answer for anyone :

```
            stop();

            try {
                //The thread used to play() the sound
                soundPlayThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            //Manually run the garbage collection and yield threads
            System.gc();
            Thread.yield();
```

I hope no one wastes 6 hours like I just did

Extreme big thanks to wuppi

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14123384/3224295