# How to move files from one drive to another drive in java

Tags: java, linux, filesystems, move

I am trying to move a file using java, from one folder to another folder, however the folders are on different hard drives, which fails to work with the **renameTo** method.  I only need this feature to work on linux...

-jason

Answer (score 2):

Moving files between different filesystems requires you to copy them. The vanilla JDK doesn't have any method to do that, you'll have to do it yourself (e.g. by using FileInputStream / FileOutputStream).

Also check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300559/move-copy-file-operations-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move files on different file Systems. Copy and Delete.

[Apache IO FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29)