# How do I move a file from one location to another in Java?

Tags: java, file, move

How do you move a file from one location to another? When I run my program any file created in that location automatically moves to the specified location. How do I know which file is moved?

Comment: First you ask about how to move one file, then you say that some files are automatically being moved. Can you make your question more clear?.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

```
myFile.renameTo(new File("/the/new/place/newName.file"));
```

[File#renameTo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) does that (it can not only rename, but also move between directories, at least on the same file system).

> Renames the file denoted by this abstract pathname.
>
> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname already exists. The return value should always be checked to make sure that the rename operation was successful.

If you need a more comprehensive solution (such as wanting to move the file between disks), look at Apache Commons [FileUtils#moveFile](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFile(java.io.File,%20java.io.File))

Comment: myFile.renameTo(new File("/the/new/place/newname.file"));

Comment: Yes, do not just give the new parent directory. And make sure the path there already exists.

Comment: Note that the object `myFile`'s path is not updated by this command. So it will be pointing to a file that is no longer there.

Comment: @Sulemankhan - yes, it also deletes the file. It really moves it on the file system

Comment: Make sure the `File` is not locked (e.g. already open) otherwise it will not be moved.

Comment: @JulienKronegg: That probably depends on your OS/filesystem. I think in Linux you can move (or delete) files that are currently open (and continue to access them through the existing file handle), but not on Windows.

Comment: Use File.separator instead of a slash. Just submitted an edit.

Comment: You need to be careful when using renameTo. If there is not enough space it doesn't throw an exception, just to give an example.

Answer (score 95):

With Java 7 or newer you can use `Files.move(from, to, CopyOption... options)`.

E.g.

```
Files.move(Paths.get("/foo.txt"), Paths.get("bar.txt"), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

See the [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) documentation for more details

Comment: got a java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException using Files.move

Answer (score 12):

**Java 6**

```
public boolean moveFile(String sourcePath, String targetPath) {

    File fileToMove = new File(sourcePath);

    return fileToMove.renameTo(new File(targetPath));
}
```

**Java 7 (Using NIO)**

```
public boolean moveFile(String sourcePath, String targetPath) {

    boolean fileMoved = true;

    try {

        Files.move(Paths.get(sourcePath), Paths.get(targetPath), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        fileMoved = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return fileMoved;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

[`File.renameTo`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) from Java IO can be used to move a file in Java. Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300559/move-copy-file-operations-in-java).

Comment: Just ensure the source file is closed before you try to rename it.

Answer (score 6):

To move a file you could also use Jakarta Commons IOs [FileUtils.moveFile](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29)

On error it throws an `IOException`, so when no exception is thrown you know that that the file was moved.

Answer (score 6):

**Just add the source and destination folder paths.**

It will move all the files and folder from source folder to 
destination folder.

```
    File destinationFolder = new File("");
    File sourceFolder = new File("");

    if (!destinationFolder.exists())
    {
        destinationFolder.mkdirs();
    }

    // Check weather source exists and it is folder.
    if (sourceFolder.exists() && sourceFolder.isDirectory())
    {
        // Get list of the files and iterate over them
        File[] listOfFiles = sourceFolder.listFiles();

        if (listOfFiles != null)
        {
            for (File child : listOfFiles )
            {
                // Move files to destination folder
                child.renameTo(new File(destinationFolder + "\\" + child.getName()));
            }

            // Add if you want to delete the source folder 
            sourceFolder.delete();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(sourceFolder + "  Folder does not exists");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Files.move(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

You can use the `Files` object

> Read more about [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html)

Comment: Just ensure the source is closed before trying to move it to target

Comment: After moving all files from source to destination it'll delete source directory as well @Daniel Taub

Answer (score 3):

You could execute an external tool for that task (like `copy` in windows environments) but, to keep the code portable, the general approach is to:

1. read the source file into memory
2. write the content to a file at the new location
3. delete the source file

`File#renameTo` will work as long as source and target location are on the same volume. Personally I'd avoid using it to move files to different folders.

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza: read the big disclaimer in Thilo's answer. It's broken in many ways on some platforms (e.g. Windows).

Answer (score 3):

Try this :-

```
  boolean success = file.renameTo(new File(Destdir, file.getName()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrote this method to do this very thing on my own project only with the replace file if existing logic in it.

```
// we use the older file i/o operations for this rather than the newer jdk7+ Files.move() operation
private boolean moveFileToDirectory(File sourceFile, String targetPath) {
    File tDir = new File(targetPath);
    if (tDir.exists()) {
        String newFilePath = targetPath+File.separator+sourceFile.getName();
        File movedFile = new File(newFilePath);
        if (movedFile.exists())
            movedFile.delete();
        return sourceFile.renameTo(new File(newFilePath));
    } else {
        LOG.warn("unable to move file "+sourceFile.getName()+" to directory "+targetPath+" -> target directory does not exist");
        return false;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
 private boolean filemovetoanotherfolder(String sourcefolder, String destinationfolder, String filename) {
            boolean ismove = false;
            InputStream inStream = null;
            OutputStream outStream = null;

            try {

                File afile = new File(sourcefolder + filename);
                File bfile = new File(destinationfolder + filename);

                inStream = new FileInputStream(afile);
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(bfile);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];

                int length;
                // copy the file content in bytes
                while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {

                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);

                }


                // delete the original file
                afile.delete();
                ismove = true;
                System.out.println("File is copied successful!");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
               inStream.close();
               outStream.close();
            }
            return ismove;
            }
```

Comment: This would be more robust if the `close` instructions  were in a `finally` block, or if it used a try-with-resources block.

Comment: I have changed it   Now it should  be ok