# Java - Move and Rename all files from one destination to another

Tags: java, file, move

I have files in one folder, i want to move them into the another folder but also and to rename them (with some static prefix value which should be added)

I succeed to list all files from the source directory but I cannot find `move` method when getting `files[i]` and I also cannot find how to rename and move files to another folder in the same time.

Can someone tell me what I should add in `getFiles` method in order to move and rename.

This is my class.

```
import java.io.File;

public class CopyTest {

    static File mainFolder = new File("F:\\TestCopy");
    static File destinationFolder = new File("F:\\TestCopy2");
    public String prefix="PREFIX";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CopyTest lf = new CopyTest();
        lf.getFiles(lf.mainFolder);

        long fileSize = mainFolder.length();

            System.out.println("File size in KB is : " + (double)fileSize/1024);

    }
    public void getFiles(File f){
        File files[];
        if(f.isFile())
            System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
        else{
            files = f.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {


                getFiles(files[i]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `file.renameto()` for moving and renaming.

Sample -

```
import java.io.File;

public class MoveFileExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try{

           File afile =new File("C:\\folderA\\Afile.txt");

           if(afile.renameTo(new File("C:\\folderB\\" + afile.getName()))){
            System.out.println("File is moved successful!");
           }else{
            System.out.println("File is failed to move!");
           }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about `yourFile.renameTo(new File("C://newpath.txt'));` ?

[how to move file from one location to another location in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645242/how-to-move-file-from-one-location-to-another-location-in-java)

You can rename it in the `new File(...)`, so get the file name and add your prefix.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html try class Files move() method.

Answer (score 1):

You can write this way

```
  import java.io.File;

public class CopyTest
{

static File mainFolder = new File("F:\\TestCopy");
static File destinationFolder = new File("F:\\TestCopy2");
public String prefix = "PREFIX";

public static void main(String str[])
{
    CopyTest lf = new CopyTest();
    lf.getFiles(lf.mainFolder);

    long fileSize = mainFolder.length();

    System.out.println("File size in KB is : " + (double) fileSize / 1024);

}

public void getFiles(File f)
{
    File files[];
    if (f.isFile())
    {
        f.renameTo(new File(destinationFolder + "\\" + prefix + f.getName()));
    }
    else
    {
        files = f.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {

            getFiles(files[i]);

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Copy File From One Folder To Another Then Remove Source file

```
/**
 * Copy File From One Folder To Another Folder
 * Then Delete File
 * @param sourceFile
 * @param destFile
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
        out = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        in.close();
        out.close();
        sourceFile.delete();
    }
}
```