# How to move a file programatically in a GitHub repository with Java?

Tags: java, git, jgit

I am using the `org.eclipse.egit.github.core` library (version 4.9.0.201710071750-r) and for the moment, I am able to push a list of files in a single commit.

I have for example `packageA/myfile.xml` and want to move it to `packageB/myfile.xml`.

I need to do it in a single commit and can be one of many operations (can be other new files, modified files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library of choice to programmatically manipulate Git repositories with Java is JGit, a pure Java implementation of Git.

In the context of your question, you would

1. move the file in question through the [Java NIO/File API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645242/how-to-move-file-from-one-location-to-another-location-in-java)
2. remove the old file (`packageA/myfile.xml`) with the [JGit RmCommand](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.3.1.201302201838-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/RmCommand.html)
3. add the moved file (`packageB/myfile.xml`) to the index with [JGit's AddCommand](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/AddCommand.html)
4. commit the moved (actually removed and then (re-) added) file

The `org.eclipse.egit.github.core` plug-in/library that you mentioned is intended to interact with GitHub's REST API. It is used as the basis for the GitHub Eclipse integration, to access and query Git repositories hosted on GitHub review pul requests and similar things.