# How To Move File From Folder To Folder

Tags: java, file

Iam Downloading A file into my Pc And Then Moving it Into

**"C:/Program Files (x86)/MyProgram/sample.txt"**

Problem is When iam Trying to Move The File From The Downloads To the Destination

Here is My Code

```
String website ="https://www.sample-videos.com/text/Sample-text-file-100kb.txt";
       try (InputStream in = URI.create(website).toURL().openStream()) {
         long x=Files.copy(in, Paths.get("C:/Users/Big Foot/Downloads/sample1.txt"));
         System.out.println(x); 
         in.close();
         File dest = new File("C:/Program Files (x86)/myProgram/sample.txt");
         File source = new File("C:/Users/Big Foot/Downloads/sample1.txt");
         try {
             FileUtils.moveFile(source, dest);
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
       }
```

**For Duplicate Claimers**  I tried This Solutions [Solution-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146153/copying-files-from-one-directory-to-another-in-java)    [Solution-2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/moving-file-one-directory-another-using-java/)  [Solution-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645242/how-do-i-move-a-file-from-one-location-to-another-in-java)But Nothing solved the problem

This Exceptions Appears to Me

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Excell To Access Convertor\sample.txt (Access is denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.doCopyFile(FileUtils.java:1123)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1076)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1028)
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFile(FileUtils.java:3008)
at download.main(download.java:31)
```

Comment: are there any exceptions?

Comment: @guleryuz  Check the Question Now I Added The Exceptions

Comment: `Access is denied`. check @Roshana Pitigala's answer

Comment: @guleryuz I know That Access Is Denied  But My Question Is  , Is There is Any Ways to Solve This Problem Without Running Program As Administrator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write or modify files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\` without administrator privileges. Running your program as administrator is the pretty much easiest way to solve this issue.

Comment: I know That Access Is Denied  But My Question Is  , Is There is Any Ways to Solve This Problem Without Running Program As Administrator