# Detecting if a file has been generated and moving a file from one directory to another

Tags: java

For Java, I have a test case scenario that involves many steps amongst which:

A- Checking whether a certain file has been generated in a certain directory.
B- moving this file from this directory to another specific directory.

How can A & B be implemented ?

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-java and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645242/how-do-i-move-a-file-from-one-location-to-another-in-java

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Selenium or streams so I removed those tags.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 1.8+, it is simple like this:

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;
...
Files.move(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
```