# How to move the file in specified folder in java?

Tags: java, file, directory, copy, move

This is my code, which I want to create method, that accept file and move it in my pc of specified folder. I just make this copy existing file of text to another text file, but I want to move in specified folder, not copy. How to solve this problem?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            InputStream inStream = null;
            OutputStream outStream = null;
    
            try {
    
                File afile = new File("C:\\Users\\anar.memmedov\\Desktop\\test.txt");
    
                File bfile = new File("C:\\Users\\anar.memmedov\\Desktop\\ok\\test3.txt");
    
                inStream = new FileInputStream(afile);
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(bfile);
    
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    
                int length;
                //copy the file content in bytes
                while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    
                    outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    
                }
    
                inStream.close();
                outStream.close();
    
                //delete the original file
                afile.delete();
    
                System.out.println("File is copied successful!");
    
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I move a file from one location to another in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645242/how-do-i-move-a-file-from-one-location-to-another-in-java)

Comment: I read this article, but there is only move to another file, not folder. I just want to accept file and move it to specified folder in my pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `Files.move`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)

> Move or rename a file to a target file.
> By default, this method attempts to move the file to the target file, failing if the target file exists except if the source and target are the same file, in which case this method has no effect. If the file is a symbolic link then the symbolic link itself, not the target of the link, is moved. This method may be invoked to move an empty directory. In some implementations a directory has entries for special files or links that are created when the directory is created. In such implementations a directory is considered empty when only the special entries exist. When invoked to move a directory that is not empty then the directory is moved if it does not require moving the entries in the directory. For example, renaming a directory on the same FileStore will usually not require moving the entries in the directory. When moving a directory requires that its entries be moved then this method fails (by throwing an IOException). To move a file tree may involve copying rather than moving directories and this can be done using the copy method in conjunction with the Files.walkFileTree utility method.

```
Path sourcePath = Paths.get("sourceFile.txt");
Path targetPath = Paths.get("targetFolder\\" + sourcePath.getFileName());

Files.move(sourcePath, targetPath);
```

Comment: it work, but When move it is looks like weird type formatter, so how to solve this?

Comment: What you mean `weird type formatter`? Can you show which paths you have?

Comment: it shows type File, not .txt or something.

Comment: @AnarMəmmədov, can you show the target path?

Comment: //        Path sourcePath = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\anar.memmedov\\Desktop\\t.txt");
//        Path targetPath = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\anar.memmedov\\Desktop\\ko\\test");
//
//        Files.move(sourcePath, targetPath);

Comment: @AnarMəmmədov As shown in detail in the linked duplicate above, you should specify the filename and file extension in your path. So your targetPath should be `Paths.get("C:\\...\\test.txt");` for example.

Comment: @AnarMəmmədov, your targetPath represents a directory. If you intend to move a file, your targetPath should represents a file. in your case: `"C:\\Users\\anar.memmedov\\Desktop\\ko\\test\\" + "t.txt"`

Comment: it worked great answer!! what if when I accept from client is it possible, to accept sending of client file and move it in specified folder?I mean +"t.txt" it is manual, but i want to accept from client?

Comment: You can get the name of file and extension from sourcePath and append it to target.

Comment: can you write this line of code?

Comment: Great Answer again! Thanks everything.! @KunLun

Comment: @KunLun I have getting this error java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\anar.memmedov\Desktop\file.xlsx -> C:\Users\anar.memmedov\Desktop\ko\file.xlsx: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Your `C:\Users\anar.memmedov\Desktop\file.xlsx` is opened by some software?