# How to move a file using Java

Tags: java, file

How to move one file (eg. .txt or .jpg) to one particular folder in Java? I want line by line explanation. I know `InputStream` and `OutputStream` read from `InputStream` and write to `OutputStream`. But how do they take bytes etc.? Any ideas?

Comment: google ( not stackoverflow ) is your friend.

Comment: I don't want to try myself but I want you to do it with line by line explanation.

Comment: you are telling us to do your homework! won't help in exams! ;)

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300559/move-copy-file-operations-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't do it by reading/writing the contents of the file.  Look at the [File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) Javadoc.  You can use the `File` class to rename and move individual files at a file level -- without having to access the contents of the files.  In particular, see the `renameTo` and `mkdirs` methods of `File`.