# how to create a program that copies specific files from one directory to another?

Tags: java, php, file-copying

suppose there is a folder 'Videos' with file names 1.avi ,2.avi ,3.avi ,4.avi .. till 100.avi .
i have created a program that outputs some numbers (let's say 92 , 31 , 92 ,85, 45 ) . now i want all the files named  92.avi , 31.avi , 92.avi ,85.avi , 45.avi  to be copied to another folder named 'Chosen Videos'
note that 92 occurs two times so i want it to be copied 2 times.first one as 92.avi and the second one 92(1).avi

how to do this in java or php

Comment: See [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300559/move-copy-file-operations-in-java) which talks about Copy/Move in Java (there is no *standard* support in JDK6) and see [File.list](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29) to get a directory file listing.

Comment: (It is also generally poor SO practice to ask a "how to" question over multiple *very distinct* languages.)

Comment: (If you're going to down-vote, please also vote to close...)

Answer (score 0):

For java, take a look at the FileUtils class [here](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).