# Is it good idea to implement USB communication through PC to android phone?

Tags: java, android, usb, file-transfer

our requirement is to implement USB file transfer from PC to android phone. I have search for 10 days and used JUSb and jan libraries but nothing worked right for me. so i am just confused that should i implement this or quite to implement. does anybody have any idea on this how i can proceed further. i konw there is default USB mass storage is available where we are doing the same thing but here my manager requires his own implementation. this can be possible but it requires lots of research and mainly TIME which we dont have much more. i need to take seriouse decision today itself to move further or not.

Comment: Yes we can implement file transfer from USB to android phone. it is very simple logic same as copying file from one drive to another so just turn on the USB mass storage after connecting the phone and run the below code.
have a great day!!! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300559/move-copy-file-operations-in-java

Answer (score 0):

As of my testing in 2012 with 4.0.3, USB file transfer to and from Android device works only under Windows 7 but not on XP and not on Ubuntu. This is because Android does not longer act as mass storage device; it uses MTP protocol instead and the support for this protocol is now required.

Windows 7 has not exactly native support but can download and install driver through Windows update.

While Ubuntu (10.04 LTS) seems providing some MTP-named packages, they seem not finished till the end in my version. Even with command line tools, I was only able to get a list of files from device but seems very slow and unstable. Big shame ...

**Update**: as of 2013, something was probably changed in Windows XP update servers as that machine unexpectedly found and downloaded the MTP driver - so now can be used to access the phone.