# how to get contents of old file of a log4j file appender in a new file for the same appender at runtime?

Tags: java, log4j

I change file appender file name in log4j at runtime.

now I want the contents of previous file to be in the new file for the appender.

Can somebody tell me how to do this ?

Initially I have log4j.properties as:

```
#log4j.appender.H.File='/home/g/connector/logs/'Y'_H.log'
#log4j.appender.H.File=/home/g/connector/logs/H.log
log4j.appender.H.File=/home/g/${logNameSuffix}.log
```

In my program, I initially do:

```
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd.HH:mm:ss");
    formattedDate = "jam" + formatter.format(date) + "_" + port;
    System.setProperty("logNameSuffix", formattedDate);
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(otherArgs[1]);
```

Then re-load as:

```
    String logName = formattedDate;

    System.clearProperty("logNameSuffix");
    System.setProperty("logNameSuffix", logName);

    LogManager.resetConfiguration();
```

what i want is that the new log created should get the old log contents also in it.

Is it possible with log4j ?

Thanks,
JJ

Comment: Why? That kind of defeats the purpose of creating a timestamped filename, and it's just as easy (easier) to deal with file concatenation on the command line.

Comment: This is becasue at time of program invocation, i don't have log file name. But I get filename sometime later in exectuon, when i have create log with that name and get all previous contents also in this new log file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it manualy: rename old file and then reset properties:

```
copyFile(new File("old file"), new File("new file"));
```

See [copyFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300559/move-copy-file-operations-in-java)

Also you can avoid System properties, and don't re-read property file, use this:

```
((FileAppender) LogManager.getRootLogger().getAppender("File")).setFile("new file");
```