# How to move files and directories

Tags: java

How to move files and directories into another directory in Java? I am using this technique to copy but I need to *move*:

```
    File srcFile = new File(file.getCanonicalPath());
    String destinationpt = "/home/dev702/Desktop/svn-tempfiles";

    copyFiles(srcFile, new File(destinationpt+File.separator+srcFile.getName()));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move / Copy File Operations in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300559/move-copy-file-operations-in-java)

Comment: @EelLee Some of the answers in there are quite outdated.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
srcFile.renameTo(new File("C:\\folderB\\" + srcFile.getName()));
```

Comment: similarly i need move a directory and file to another directory at a same time

Comment: this can also move a file to another directory

Answer (score 2):

Have you read this "http://java.about.com/od/InputOutput/a/Deleting-Copying-And-Moving-Files.htm
"

```
    Files.move(original, destination, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
```

move the files to destination.

If you want to move directory
Use this

```
     File dir = new File("FILEPATH");
     if(dir.isDirectory()) {
     File[] files = dir.listFiles();
     for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
       //move files[i]
     }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Java.io.File does not contains any ready make move file method, but you can workaround with the following two alternatives :

1. File.renameTo()
2. Copy to new file and delete the original file.

   ```
   public class MoveFileExample 
   {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     { 
     try{

      File afile =new File("C:\\folderA\\Afile.txt");

      if(afile.renameTo(new File("C:\\folderB\\" + afile.getName()))){
       System.out.println("File is moved successful!");
      }else{
       System.out.println("File is failed to move!");
      }

   }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }
   }
   ```

For Copy and delete

```
public class MoveFileExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   

        InputStream inStream = null;
    OutputStream outStream = null;

        try{

            File afile =new File("C:\\folderA\\Afile.txt");
            File bfile =new File("C:\\folderB\\Afile.txt");

            inStream = new FileInputStream(afile);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(bfile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int length;
            //copy the file content in bytes 
            while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0){

                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);

            }

            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();

            //delete the original file
            afile.delete();

            System.out.println("File is copied successful!");

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

HOPE IT HELPS :)